# What is the environment variable in VS2017 for path of xsd.exe?

Tags: xsd, visual-studio-2017

In convert my project files from VS2013 to VS2017.
The environment variable $(SDK40ToolsPath) does not exist anymore.
What is the alternative in VS2017?